# Most efficient way to query this in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an array of permission groups, like Admin, Moderator etc... I want to query the SQL database and retrieve the amount of people with these groups... Here is my code:

```
$groups = $this->getGroupsUsingPermission("sabre.access");
foreach($groups as $g) {
    $command = "SELECT COUNT(PERMISSION_GROUP) FROM users 
                WHERE PERMISSION_GROUP='".$g."';";
    $query = mysqli_query($this->connection, $command) or die (mysqli_error()); 
    $amountOfStaff = $amountOfStaff + mysqli_fetch_row($query)[0];
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this other than querying the database over and over?

**UPDATE:**

I mean like this:

```
groups:
    member:
        permissions:
            - sabre.access
    admin
        permissions:
            - sabre.admin
        inheritance:
            - member
```

Now, I have this working, along with the inheritance. It returns an array like:

```
member, admin (any other groups which have access to 'sabre.access' etc...)
```

So when I set someone's group like this:

```
ID, USERNAME, PERMISSION_GROUP
 1   Kieron         Owner
```

I want to count everyone who has any one of those groups which are in the array, you get me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use MySQL's [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) to search all of the groups at once:

```
$groups = $this->getGroupsUsingPermission("sabre.access");
$group_ids = implode("','", $groups)
$command = "SELECT COUNT(PERMISSION_GROUP) FROM users WHERE PERMISSION_GROUP IN('".$group_ids."');";
$query = mysqli_query($this->connection, $command) or die (mysqli_error()); 
$amountOfStaff = $amountOfStaff + mysqli_fetch_row($query)[0];
```

Here I use `implode()` to take the group IDs and make them a comma separated string. I then make that the value we pass to `IN()`. You could also use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) here as well.

```
$groups = $this->getGroupsUsingPermission("sabre.access");
$group_ids = implode(',', $groups)
$command = "SELECT COUNT(PERMISSION_GROUP) FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET(PERMISSION_GROUP, '".$group_ids."');";
$query = mysqli_query($this->connection, $command) or die (mysqli_error()); 
$amountOfStaff = $amountOfStaff + mysqli_fetch_row($query)[0];
```

Comment: getGroupsUsingPermission("sabre.access") returns the groups as the data type of String. So I'll have groups like, "Moderator", "Admin", "Owner". I want to be able to count all the people in the database with any of those groups specified.

Comment: @user3195557 I updated my answer to work with string ids

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want count of users in each group ?

```
    $groups = $this->getGroupsUsingPermission("sabre.access");
    $group_ids = implode(',', $groups)
    $command = "SELECT PERMISSION_GROUP, COUNT(*) userCount FROM users 
                WHERE PERMISSION_GROUP IN (".$group_ids.")
                Group By PERMISSION_GROUP";
    $query = mysqli_query($this->connection, $command) or die (mysqli_error()); 
    $amountOfStaff = $amountOfStaff + mysqli_fetch_row($query)[0];
```